# Get request with Rapture Http

Tags: scala, http, rapture.io

I'm building an API with Rapture in Scala and having trouble resolving an issue with an implicit not being in scope. Here is the output from the error that I'm receiving.

```
[error] /Users/Petesta/Documents/scala-project/src/main/scala/scala-project/main.scala:35: an implicit TimeSystem is required; please import timeSystems.numeric or timeSystems.javaUtil
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]     val response = h.get()
[error]                         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Oct 16, 2014 3:36:10 PM
```

Here is the code that it is failing on.

```
def getUser(userName: String) = {
    val h = Http / "some_url" / "user" / userName /? Map('key -> "value")
    val response = h.get()
}
```

I'm not sure what to do because I've tried importing both libraries separately and the error is still the same.

I've also added the `-Xlog-implicits` flag to see if something else is causing the error but no additional information is outputted.

Is there a good resource anywhere with using the rapture-net library for HTTP requests? I couldn't find one except for Jon Pretty's slides at *Scala By The Bay*. I couldn't figure out a way to pass in a url with query strings into rapture-uri since it expects function invocation to look like this `uri"url_dot_domain_with_query_strings".slurp[Char]`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you were mentioning *Jon Pretty* at Sbtb?

Answer (score 2):

The compilation error is not entirely correct in this case. You need 1 of the 2 imports AND you need to specify a timeout value.

```
def getUser(userName: String) = {
  import timeSystems.numeric
  val h = Http / "some_url" / "user" / userName /? Map('key -> "value")
  val response = h.get(timeout = 5000L)
}
```

I don't really know of a good resource on it, but your basic single code line is correct. The biggest problem with the library is really documentation about the imports required. But this is what I found works for me:

```
def getGoogle() = {
  import rapture.codec._
  import rapture.io._
  import rapture.uri._
  import rapture.net._
  import encodings.`UTF-8`
  uri"http://google.com".slurp[Char]
}
```